# Redirecting to external url, resulting in 404 laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes

I thought this would be fairly simple, but I'm stumped.

I have a link on my site nav that goes to an aws pdf file and works fine. I'm trying to create a named route that a user could type in and also redirect to that file but I'm getting a 404.

I've tried:

```
Route::get('Documents', function () {

    return redirect()->away('http://s3.aws/documents.pdf');

});

Route::get('Documents', function () {

    return redirect()->to('http://s3.aws/documents.pdf');

});

    Route::get('Documents', function () {

    return redirect('http://s3.aws/documents.pdf');

});
```

And they all result in 404 when I visit www.mysite.com/Documents

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right aws link?

Comment: Yes I copied it from the working link to the route

Comment: It would be useful to know what's the error when you type `php artisan route:list` as if Laravel cannot list routes, more likely it isn't gonna register them when you request the site, so you get these 404s

Comment: Good point. It's a syntax error in routes.php and then a stacktrace of 5 errors from bootstrap/cache/compiled.php

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```php
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Read more about [laravel redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects) here.

Comment: I just put this in as well, Still getting a 404 though

Comment: I tested it here and it's working. Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: This is my test:
`Route::get('/test', function(){return
\Redirect::to('https://google.com');});`

This is the url, if you want to see: https://mateusjunges.com/test

Comment: Hmm. I used to have a public directory for the site named Documents as well but I renamed it. COuld it have caused an error?

Comment: the test you posted also gets a 404. It's like it won't let me redirect externally. I have one other redirect in my routes file to an internal url that works fine and I structured it the same

Comment: Try again, i post `/test` but my route was `/teste` xD. `/test` works now

Comment: I'm baffled, none of it's working. Never had this issue before either

Comment: Question : when I run php artisan route:list and route:clear they do not work but instead show a fatal exception stack trace on something entirely different. Could that point to something

Comment: Yes, maybe. But i can't say it with 100% certainty. Need more info.